# iptables: find out what packet is blocked by which rule?

Tags: iptables

How can I setup iptables in a way I know what packet is blocked by which rule? The one solution I know of is to -j LOG --log-prefix. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at packet/byte counters:

> Chain FIREWALL (2 references)
> **pkts bytes** target     prot opt in     out     source              destination
>
> **73M   42G** ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

You can clear the counters with the '-Z' option.  You can direct types of packets to their own table and accept them individually based on the source if you want to track the source.

```
iptables -N SMTP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j SMTP
iptables -A SMTP -s $network_1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A SMTP -s $network_2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A SMTP -j RETURN

#Track by network instead of application
iptables -N NETWORK_1 
iptables -I INPUT -s $network_1 -j NETWORK_1
iptables -A NETWORK_1 -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "MAIL"
iptables -A NETWORK_1 -p udp --dport 10000:20000 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "VOIP RTP"
iptables -A NETwORK_1 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A NETWORK_1 -p tcp -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "UNKNOWN TCP"
iptables -A NETWORK_1 -j RETURN -m comment --comment "This rule is not required but used for ip accounting"
```

Comment: Don't forget the command to peek at those counters: `iptables -L -v -n`.

Answer (score 1):

There is also -j ULOG, that you can use together with ulogd.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the `TRACE` target

> This target marks packets so that the
>   kernel will log every rule which match
>   the packets as those tra-verse  the 
>   tables,  chains, rules. (The ipt_LOG
>   or ip6t_LOG module is required for the
>   logging.) The packets are logged with
>   the string prefix: "TRACE:
>   tablename:chainname:type:rulenum "
>   where type can be  "rule" for plain
>   rule, "return" for implicit rule at
>   the end of a user defined chain and
>   "policy" for the policy of the built
>   in chains. It can only be used in the
>   raw table.